# Referring Tomcat Static Resource File inside Spring Resource Loader

Tags: java, spring, tomcat9, staticresource

I have defined a static resource XML file (users.xml) and configure it in Tomcat's server.xml file as shown below to access it from outside the WAR file:

```
   <Host name="localhost"  appBase="webapps" unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">

        <Context docBase="D:/rest-api-data-v2/user"  path="/user" />

   </Host>
```

Next, I defined a Resource Loader Spring bean.

```
<bean id="customResourceLoader" class="com.javamas.rest.data.util.CustomResourceLoader" >
    <property name="resource">
        <value>http://localhost:8080/user/users.xml</value>
    </property>
</bean>
```

I also tried to specify URl prefix but it didn't help.

```
<bean id="customResourceLoader" 
    class="com.javamas.rest.data.util.CustomResourceLoader" >
    <property name="resource">
        <value>url:http://localhost:8080/user/users.xml</value>
    </property>
</bean>
```

But I am getting `FileNotFoundException` while accessing the `InputStream` from Resource. However, if I provide the file as

```
<property name="resource">
    <value>file:D:/rest-api-data-v2/user/users.xml</value>
</property>
```

then I can access the file.

I followed these two links.

https://www.techsupper.com/2017/05/serve-static-resources-from-external-folder-outside-webapps-tomcat.html

https://howtodoinjava.com/spring-core/spring-resource-loader-aware/

What's wrong with my configuration?.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: I don't know for Spring, but I do  think rather strange to rely on http://localhost:8080. You could probably, but the server localhost:8080 would have first to exists/be started. Is it started?

Comment: Yes. Server is started.